# Unknown campaign labeled as Private has suddenly appeared in GA campaigns section

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering if anyone can help with this. I recently viewed my campaigns tab in Google Analytics where I have two campaigns running and was surprised to find a third (not added by me) called "Private". I clicked through to the campaign details and the source/medium listed is "Viber / Chat".

I run a single author blog and only I have access to Google Analytics for my site. I have not created this campaign, I do however have a mobile share bar on the site that includes a Viber button. Could this be it?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user shares an url in the viber chat app. The app automatically adds utm parameters source : Viber Medium = Chat and Campaign = Private (because it's a private conversation).

Answer (score 0):

Anybody can point a URL with campaign query strings (utm parameters) at your site and traffic that goes through that URL will show up in your Campaigns report. But yes it's just as likely you are the one unknowingly pointing a campaign at your site. What is the URL sent via Viber from your site? If the utm_campain parameter = viber then youve found your culprit!

Comment: Hi samthebrand, thanks for your reply. I'm not entirely sure how to find the utm for it in GA, could you tell me how I could locate it? I suspected the share buttons, but the strange thing is I haven't made any changes to the plugin for months and the campaign showed up only recently.  Many thanks again.

Comment: @DigitalFrog the utm may be in the url being shared by the share button. Copy that link and paste it somewhere and see if its there.

Answer (score 0):

For suspect traffic, my first check is to apply a secondary dimension of 'Hostname'. If it doesn't match the hostname of your site, it's almost certainly spam and should be ignored.